# Android weird drawing canvas bug?

Tags: android, android-canvas

let's get straight to the point, I was making an android game and I decided to try and use some more android methods like `Rect` and `Path` so I can experiment and learn how they work. (in the past I used only bitmaps to draw graphics)

As I was making the game I noticed some weird coloring on my rects, so I tried a lot of things, I made sure my rects are initialized properly and I also tried to simplify my code to make sure the problem was caused there.

For debug purposes my code draws a white square on the top left side of the screen, a black on the top right, and a gray one on the bottom, this is the code:

```
Paint pGray, pWhite, pBlack;

public myClass()
{
    paintGray = new Paint();
    paintGray.setARGB(255, 125, 125, 125);

    paintWhite = new Paint();
    paintWhite.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);

    paintBlack = new Paint();
    paintBlack.setARGB(255, 0, 0, 0);
}

public void draw(Canvas canvas)
{
    canvas.drawRect(0, screenHeight/2, screenWidth, screenHeight, paintGray);
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, screenWidth/2, screenHeight/2, paintWhite);
    canvas.drawRect(screenWidth/2, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight/2, paintBlack);
}
```

(I don't know if it matters but it runs on another `Thread`)

When I run it on my phone and save a screenshot using Android Studio the screenshot looks like this:

[image]

which is t he desired result, the problem is that my phone doesn't display the graphics properly and here is a photo:

[image]

As you can see the gray square has 2 colors inside it, a darker and a lighter one. It happens on both phones that I have and I have no idea what it is, even weirder is that saving the screenshot doesn't show this problem!!

I also noticed the colorization changes based on the white square, if I make it bigger or smaller the gray square changes its color where the white box ends.

Another thing I noticed is that these lines of "decolorization" (with multiple white boxes, multiple lines appear) on the gray square is vertical on landscape mode, but on portrait it becomes horizontal.

I've been torturing my self for so much time with this, I have commented out my whole application to try and see why it happens, if I'm missing something or anyone knows anything please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's a software bug. My guess would be that that's the way the display is rendering colors.

Comment: Given that the screenshot shows no error it seems that way, but is it a good idea to ignore it? It looks annoying especially when there is a character running and one of those lines following him on the ground

Comment: I'm not a graphic designer but it's not very common to use "full black" of "full white" colors (in nature nothing is #FFFFFF). I suggest taming the palette a little bit :D Also, the effect will not be as visible when any texture is applied to the elements.

Comment: In my original project i was using other colors but full white and full black seem to amplify this bug, in my game i had more greyish colors but it was still visible (i made them black and white for the purpose of this question) , with textures it wont be visible but it will still be there and its bugging me! :P

Comment: Lol thats a good idea haha i might consider it :P thx for the answer !

Comment: If that solved the issue, can you please accept the answer? Not only I will get my precious points but also the question will not show up as unanswered.

Comment: I want to wait to see if anyone knows more  about this, if  not i will accept yours